# No ejecuta evento click

Tags: javascript, php

Este es el codigo que tengo del boton(Las variables las igualo a resultado de una consulta, he comprobado y estan bien):

```
 echo '<input type="button" value="ELIMINAR" class="btnForm" onClick="eliminar('.$idEvento.','.$nombre.')" /> ';
```

Ahora vemos el codigo de la funcion eliminar:

```
function eliminar(id,nombre)
        {
            if(confirm('¿Estas seguro de que desea eliminar la actividad?')){
                location.href="eliminacion.php?id="+id+"&nombre="+nombre;
                return true;}
            else
                return false;
        }
```

y este el ecodigo del archivo eliminacion.php:

```
require '../php/eventos.php';



                        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

                        $idEvento = $_GET["id"];
                        $nombre = $_GET["nombre"];
                //echo $_GET["id"];
                            //echo $_GET["nombre"];
                        }

                        // Tratar retorno
                        $retorno = Eventos::delete($idEvento);

                        if ($retorno) {
                            echo '<div class="mensajes5seg">';
                            echo '<h1>Has eliminado la actividad --> '.$nombre.'</h1>';
                             echo '<h3>La página se redireccionará en 5 segundos...</h3>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        } else {
                            // Enviar respuesta de error general
                            print json_encode(
                                array(
                                    'estado' => '2',
                                    'mensaje' => 'No se obtuvo el registro'
                                )
                            );
                        }
```

Ahora bien le doy al boton y no hace nada cuando antes pasando un solo parametro si lo hacia, no veo el fallo, alguna ayuda?

Comment: `onclick` se escribe todo en minuscula.

Comment: no pero eso no es, lo acabo de probar y nada, ademas antes lo tenia igual y si lo hacia. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: de acuerdo, algunos navegadores lo soportan dependiendo del DOCTYPE, pero XML (y SGML) son case-sesitive en el markup por definicion, tenlo en cuenta. Ahora, te has fijado en la consola si hay algun error?

Comment: ¿has revisado en la consola de error de Javascript si se produce algún error? no tiene sentido preguntar antes de mirar los log de error del servidor y navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Te ahorras problemas si en lugar de echo, cierras llave y colocas HTML normal. Además, queda más legible.

```
?> // cierre de php
<button class="btnForm" onClick="eliminar(<?=$idEvento?>, <?=$nombre?>)">Eliminar</button>
<?php // vuelves a abrir php y sigues
```

Comment: Aunque tu comentario es correcto, no es una respuesta a la pregunta. Por tanto debería ser un comentario a la pregunta, no una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no te esta reconociendo las comillas (**''**) por eso no esta entrando al evento, intenta hacerlo de esta manera

```
echo '<input type="button" value="ELIMINAR" class="btnForm" onClick="eliminar(\"'.$idEvento.'\",\"'.$nombre.'\")" /> ';
```

Para enviar los datos podrías utilizar [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), quedaria algo asi:

```
function eliminar(id,nombre){
  if(confirm('¿Estas seguro de que desea eliminar la actividad?')){

    $.ajax({
           url: 'eliminacion.php',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'html',
           data: {
                  id: id,
                  nombre: nombre
           },
           success:function(respuesta){
             // respuesta, trae el array() o el mensaje dependiendo de el caso 
             return true;
           }
        });
   }else{
      return false;
   }
  }
```

Para capturar los datos en la pagina [php](/questions/tagged/php) podrias hacerlo con **$_REQUEST['']**, Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: ok gracias voy a mirar, lo de ajax estuve mirandolo pero todavia soy un poco novato en esto, poco a poco jeje de nuevo gracias